# Why do my LED bulbs refuse to work in one socket but CFLs will work?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have 3 lights over my desk operated by 1 simple switch.  I replaced all 3 with LED bulbs.  Two of the lights work fine, but the other will work for a while and then stop.  I tried 4 of the bulbs that work fine in the first 2 sockets, but would not work in this one socket.  When I took them out and put them back in the first 2 sockets, they worked fine again.

What's going on?
Is the socket bad or something else? CFL bulbs work fine in it.

Comment: Does the suspect socket fail when all other sockets are vacant?

Comment: The center contact in the problem socket may not be projecting out far enough. Turn the switch off and use a crochet hook or a small screwdriver to pry up the contact.

Comment: How much heat do the LEDs generate?  Good products don't but I've seen el cheapo ballasted lamps that get hot as heck.  If that the case it may be the thermal overide in the fixture. Why that can only? Different building conditions/insulation.   PS - if you do have an LED bulb with an el cheapo ballast the bulb is not saving electricity like LEDs should.  Heat=Energy consumption.

Comment: Does the lamp have any kind of powered or active *anything* - lighted switch, motion sensor, dimmer, yadayada?  I'm guessing you're on the lookout for those, but something like that is a common reason.  Also look at the "bulb" bases - is the new one wider/fatter?  Sometimes this means the bulb can't quite screw in all the way.